# Deployment of Logic Apps Integration Account with PowerShell error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-logic-apps

I use the powershell `New-AzureRmIntegrationAccountSchema` to deploy a schema to an integration account.

It worked in the past but now I have this error :

> Unable to deserialize the response.

Unfortunately I don't have more details on the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide the code you've tried with `New-AzureRmIntegrationAccountSchema`

Comment: Could you create a new schema on Azure Portal.

Comment: Please use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
` to get your Azure Power Shell version. The latest version is 4.4.1. I test in my lab, your cmdlet works for me.

Comment: To be more specific, I start the PowerShell cmdlet in Release Pipeline, so I think that I have the latest version of PowerShell.
And when I have this issue, I can add manually the schemas in the portal.

Is it possible to have more details about the exception I received from the cmdlet?

Comment: And here is the command line I use:
New-AzureRmIntegrationAccountSchema -ResourceGroupName "$resourceGroupName" -Name "$iacName" -SchemaName "$baseName" -SchemaFilePath "$fullName" -ErrorAction Stop

The XSD I'm trying to deploy comes from the build artefact associated with my release pipeline. When I start the same command outside of Release pipeline I have the same error.

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER Hi, `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` could you check your Azure Power Shell version?

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER Add `$DebugPreference="Continue"` could print before cmldet will print more debug information.

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER The [xsd](https://prod-21.southcentralus.logic.azure.com/integrationAccounts/b98d61c0fc364dbebc439bd4579d3046/schemas/Order/contents/Value?api-version=2015-08-01-preview&se=2017-11-10T10%3A29%3A43.8392744Z&sp=%2Fschemas%2FOrder%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=nRMYzI963755H9cIz6rl0u0KDKVNNOiM5js7O2wPVOs) works for me fine. Maybe you could try. Let us know if this is a Powershell issue or your xml issue.

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER Also, if possible, you could share your xml file. I will test on my lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set the PowerShell version to 2.1.0 in the Release Pipeline and now it works :)

Comment: Power Shell 2.1.0 is also a older version. I think the cmdlet will works fine on latest version.

Comment: But your issue is a Power Shell version issue. Hope it will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I suggest you could test your xml file on Azure Portal to know whether this is a Power Shell issue or your xml issue.

If your xml works fine on Azure Portal. You could check your Azure Power Shell version with following cmdlet.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

I test on 4.4.1 version, it works for me. You could download the msi installer from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v4.4.1-October2017).

If it also does not work, you could add `$DebugPreference="Continue"` to print more debug log.

Update:

It is a Power Shell version issue, OP use older version Power Shell, when set the Power Shell version to 2.1.0, the issue is resolved. I test in my lab, if we use the latest version, the cmdlet also works.